# Calling shell commands from Java web application

Tags: java, web-services, shell, exec

I am working on Java Web Application by creating web services in it.  From one of the service I need to call the shell level commands, for which I am using the following:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

At execution time I am getting following error "CreateProcess error=2" after which the server gets terminated.

Any idea what can be wrong, or is there any other better method to call the shell commands from the web service hosted on servers like Tomcat

Standard code that I am using in web service:

```
        @RequestMapping("/user/testDetails")
        public UserResult testDetails(@RequestParam(value="username") String username) {
            System.out.println("Inside User Details REST");
            User user = userService.getUserByName(username);            
            String s = null;             
            try {                
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dir");                
                BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                     InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));     
                BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                     InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
                System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
                while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }                
                System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
                while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }                
               // System.exit(0);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
                e.printStackTrace();
                //System.exit(-1);
            }           
            return new UserResult(user, "1", null);
        }
```

Comment: Something is wrong with "command"?  Please show more of your code than the one line.

Comment: check `$PATH` or use absolute path of command

Comment: I am trying it with simple commands like "ls -l" , "dir" neither is working

Comment: Try using the full path to your command.